# Getting User.Identity.Name after AspNet OpenAuth Login MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

I am using OAuth to sing the user up with Facebook.

I am doing successful signup using the following method:-

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(id);
```

This Autheticates the user. I can check this using **User.Identity.IsAuthenticated**

But I am not able to get the name of the User or any of his details using **User.Identity.Name**.

How can I get the name of the User who has just been authenticated without going back to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best response that thing I came up with is adding claims and adding the Name claim to the answer.

```
var newClaims = new Claim[]
                        {
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, PersonId.ToString()),
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, FirstName),
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, LastName),
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, FirstName + LastName),
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, Email)
                        };
```

The Name claim that I added would fill the User.Identity.Name field.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't get anything from `User.Identity.Name` is because there's no actual user record to pull that info from, which means hitting the database wouldn't help you anyways. Sign-in provider logins are handled separately from system user logins, in a separate table in fact. They can and often are tied to an actual user account, but they don't have to be. The provider login is enough to authenticate, and sometimes that may be all that's needed. If you do actually need the user information, then you'll need to create a user record after successful provider login and associate that with the provider login.

Comment: I have the user record in the claims. How can I associate that with the provider Login?

Comment: No, you have the user object the sign-in provider returns as part of the OAuth standard in the claims. What you don't have is an actual record in your own database. You can use the user object in the claim to populate your application's user entity to save a record to your database. However, there's not enough information here to help you further, as the process differs greatly depending on what version of MVC you're using and what authentication system your using.

Comment: I am using MVC 5.0. I have created a record in the database. I am using the method of external cookie to get the user logged in. Where I save the claims in the external cookie. Once I read the claims I feed them into a person Object and destroy the external cookie. I register the person in the database. Now I want the name of the person without making a database call. What can be done in that case?